# AJAX error - Indirect reference is being made to assembly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm upgrading a project from the v2.0 framework to the v4.5.1 framework and I'm getting the following error...

> Indirect reference is being made to assembly System.Web.Extensions version 4.0.0.0, which contains 'AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender'. This Project references a prior version of System.Web.Extensions version 1.0.61025.0. To use 'AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender', you must replace the reference to System.Web.Extensions with version 4.0.0.0 or higher.

My question is what do I need to change in my web.config so that my project will compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keith,

In order to resolve this issue you need to change the target framework from 2.0 to 4.0 or later (In your case 4.5.1) in the solution's properties.

Once you have done this  rebuild your solution web.config settings should work again.